# How can I append an existing PDF to a generated PDF with flying saucer for Java

Tags: java, flying-saucer

I have some PDFs generated out of velocity templates. A new requirement now is to append an **existing** PDF to the generated one and deliver both as one.
I read a lot about that approach but could not find any mentioned API method to achieve this.

Can somebody guide me to the solution?

Comment: So I generate one with flying saucer and have two pdfs which I merge together with the mentioned library you linked?

Comment: If two PDFs are correct PDF you can merge them with any library, incl. the one, mentioned in the link.